# android canvas drawing

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have a problem in saving the canvas image drawn. Here is the code:

```
public void save_it(File file)
{
    String fname = file.getAbsolutePath();
    MyView mv =new MyView(this);
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try{
        fos = new FileOutputStream(fname);
        mv.myBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        Toast.makeText(this,"Image Saved", 2000).show();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Error Saving Image", 2000).show();
        Log.i("DAVE","stacktrace is " + e);
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem? Where's the stack trace? What is `MyView`? Does its `myBitmap` field get initialized at construction? (P.S.: Please use the three-argument Log methods: `Log.i("DAVE","stacktrace follows", e);`

Answer (score 0):

you should close the `FileOutputStream` when you do not need it.

after `mv.myBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);`

add `fos.close()` and check if something changes.

PS. Always post the content of your logcat.